# Why aren't update to a Joomla custom module aren't being displayed on live site?

Tags: joomla

I have been editing a module in Joomla that lets me display custom HTML in it. On the live site the link URL is "/index.php?Itemid=17" but when I go to edit the HTML of the link in the module editor the module editor shows the HTML link being "index.php?option=com_rsform&Itemid=17".

Notice how there is the "option=com_rsform" in there now? I have verified that the module I'm editing is in fact the same one on the production site by enabling and disabling it and seeing it be removed and added to the production site. But it seems like the module might be stripping out the "option=com_rsform" part of the URL?

Does anyone know what the reason might be for Joomla to act like this? I am new to Joomla so it might be something obvious I don't know about.

The module type name is "mod_custom".

Here is the full HTML from the module.

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><a href="index.php?option=com_rsform&Itemid=17"><img alt="webinar" style="border-style: none; border-width: 0px; margin: 5px; vertical-align: middle;" src="images/stories/webinar.jpg" width="265" height="213" /></a></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the site is configured to use SEF (Search Engine Friendly) urls, then that may be causing the URL to change from what you are setting in the module to what you are seeing in the live site.

Try editing the url to see the result in the live site, for example:

```
index.php?Itemid=17&option=com_rsform&key=value
```

Also, you could check that "com_rsform" is an actual component reference and that pasting the url directly into the browser works.